# Ehcache query paged

Tags: ehcache

There is any way to paginate one Ehcache query from X item to Y item in the index?

```
    Query query = getCache().createQuery();

    Attribute<String> did = new Attribute("did");
    Attribute<Date> activity = new Attribute("activity");
    Attribute<Double> latitude = new Attribute("latitude");
    Attribute<Double> longitude = new Attribute("longitude");

    query
            .addOrderBy(activity, Direction.DESCENDING)
            .includeAttribute(did)
            .includeAttribute(activity)
            .includeAttribute(latitude)
            .includeAttribute(longitude)
            .includeValues()
            .end();

    Results results = query.execute();

    // To do in query???
    List<Result> page = results.range(range * 20, (range + 1) *20);
```

After call the execute() method, I know the Results.range(int, int) method does it, but I want only get the focus items.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, Dani!

Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463747/hql-select-range-of-results) solution from stackoverflow.

Comment: Sergey, that solution is about HQL, this question is about Ehcache Querys.

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe is the way to do it.

What you are querying for contains an `orderBy` clause, so it cannot even be correct without looking at all the results anyway.

Remember also that this is a cache you are dealing with, two queries at different time may return different results as a consequence of expiry or eviction taking place. In this context, trying to get specific range of results across query executions may show duplicate or missed results.

Comment: My question is for a simple reason, I could have milles of entry items in that cache region, but in every query only has the purpose to get 20 of those items. Then, in a first glance, it can seen a bad performance with one Result which contains too much useless items., But good, can you answer me if the situation exposed below is better than get all items?

Answer (score 0):

Is this manner a good aproximation to get more performance?

```
query
    .addOrderBy(activity, Direction.DESCENDING)
    .includeAttribute(activity)
    .includeValues()
    .maxResults((range + 1) * 20)
    .end();

List<Result> page = query.execute().range(range * 20, (range + 1) * 20);
```

I use one activity Date property, set when the item is push on cache to avoid the problem exposed by Louis Jacomet previusly.